# Добавить ограничение в стандартной Django админке

Tags: django

Есть в админке юзеры, им даны права на добавление и редактирование материалов. Однако когда юзер у которого есть данные права заходит в материалы, он видет там все материалы, и свои, и чужие.

Как сделать так чтобы каждый юзер видел только свои материалы, те которые он добавил? Следовательно и редактировать мог тоже, только свои. (где подобный фильтр прописывается, дабы повлияло на админку?)

У таблицы материалов есть поле **user_id(Foreign Keys - User)**, то есть, каждый материал знает кто его создавал.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно смотреть в сторону метода `queryset` класса `ModelAdmin`:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
```

[ModelAdmin.queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset)

Answer (score 0):

Точно не знаю, но, по-моему, такого фильтра "из коробки" не предоставляется, а написать свой не составит труда. Вот [здесь](http://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2009/07/30/django-admin-custom-filterspecs/) есть хороший пример, как это сделать.

Comment: Попробовать можно, если не выйдет так, буду как @qnub предложил делать.

Answer (score 0):

Нет такого. Админка в джанго это что-то вроде root в *nix - не стоит пускать в неё модераторов/менеджеров и прочий сервисный люд, для них нужно писать свои, более высокоуровневые интерфейсы, которые будут учитывать всю бизнес-логику приложения.

Comment: Что-то в этом есть. Однако немного не согласен. В админке есть возможность делать пользователей модераторами, и есть возможность создавать группы, там и там раздавать права, значит создатели ориентировались на то что все подобные действия будут производиться в стандартной админке. Понятно если мне нужно полностью всю логику менять и дофига фич, то проще новую написать, но если дело в одном фильтре, то мне все же кажется можно и каким-то условием отделаться в стандартной. Могу быть не правым, мнение субъективно.

Comment: Группы и права есть, но они для использования в сайте, в том числе и во вучную написанных интерфейсах для модераторов (я, к примеру, не верю в компетенцию людей не программистов разобраться в голой админке Джанго и ничего при этом не запороть). Т.е. админка - такая штука где на низком уровне можно что-то добавить/убрать/исправить. К примеру лень делать интерфейс для действия которое совершается раз в 2 года (скажем задать те же права) - зашёл в админку и там сделал, но пускать туда всех... Не целесообразно и опасно.

Comment: Не совсем согласен. Джанго админка на столько проста что там и ребенок разберется. То что не поломать, дык на это и права нужны, если я разрешаю добавлять материалы, то кроме как добавить новый (заполнив 4 строчки и выбрав одну фотку), они больше ничего не мугут, и ничего друго-го и не видят.
Хотя для подобных действий написать свою админку конечно круто, при этом её сделав уникальной и юзабилетной.
По этому считаю что это зависит от желания реализатора. А сделать можно и так и так. ИМХО создатели были бы не против 2х способов.

Comment: Вообще джанго такая штука, как и питон, можно всё что угодно... Просто мне не кажется переделывание админки (включая дизайн) более простым, нежели создание нескольких страниц с формами и выводом заранее ограниченными нужными требованиями и проводящими все необходимые проверки и дополнительные манипуляции. Но, коенчно, в каждом конкретном случае есть свои более оптимальные варианты.